# Компоновщик не может найти функцию

Tags: c++

Пишу программу подбора фильмов пользователю на основе ранее понравившихся ему фильмов. Привел вроде как в рабочее состояние парсер файла лайков, но вот не задача: выдает 6 ошибок [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=RU-RU&k=k(LNK2019)&rd=true) на неразрешенный внешний символ(судя по [LINK1120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=RU-RU&k=k(LNK1120)&rd=true) там 3 таких места), вроде как что-то не то с `inline getId() const`.

*Пример ошибок:*

> Ошибка    LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 3  FilmSelection
>
> C:\Users\Andrey\Documents\GitHub\FilmSelection\FilmSelection\FilmSelection\De
>   bug\FilmSelection.exe 1

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall Channel::getId(void)const "
>   (?getId@Channel@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   в функции "public: class std::shared_ptr __thiscall
>   User::findChannel(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (?findChannel@User@@QAE?AV?$shared_ptr@VChannel@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z) FilmSelection   C:\Users\Andrey\Documents\GitHub\FilmSelection\FilmSelection\FilmSelection\FilmSelection\User.obj   1

```
inline string Channel::getId() const; // public метод, который я вызываю через shared pointer на данный класс
{
   return id; //id является private string
}
//поиск фильма, у Film есть аналогичный метод получения getId(), films - это list<shared_ptr<Film>> films 
//increaseLikes() увеличивает количество лайков для канала и аналогично для фильма
shared_ptr<Film> Channel::findFilm(string id_film) 
{
    for (auto it = films.begin(); it != films.end(); it++)
        if (id_film == (*it)->getId()) {
            (*it)->increaseLikes();
            return (*it);
        }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Вот исходник [GITHUB](https://github.com/Xambey/FilmSelection/tree/test/FilmSelection/FilmSelection)

Comment: Эх, зачем же вы папки Debug и Release да в git..

Comment: Попробуйте убрать inline.

Comment: @free_ze помогло, спасибо! Но почему???? Так же вроде принято делать при получении данных

Comment: @free_ze ошибку выдавал потому что Inline вставляет по месту вызова код целиком, а return в if() не очень?

Comment: @Xambey Потому что инлайн-функции должны определяться вместе с типом, т.е. в хэдере, аналогично шаблонам. Я скопипащу свой коммент в ответ.

Comment: @free_ze т.е если я добавлю inline только в заголовочном файле, то все будет работать?

Comment: @Xambey Будет. Тот же эффект будет, если вы определите метод прямо в теле класса Channel.

Comment: @free_ze при наличии `inline` только в объявлении (без определения) [всё равно будет](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1dtfrScHhtDubxqL) `undefined reference`.

Comment: @alexolut Было бы странно, если бы было иначе =) Я же говорил об [этом](http://ideone.com/09FzFV)

Comment: @free_ze я опирался на [комментарий ТС](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548629/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e?noredirect=1#comment702062_548629). Вы же на него отвечали, не так ли?

Comment: @alexolut А если принять во внимание мой [предыдущий комментарий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548629/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E?noredirect=1#comment702060_548629)?

Comment: @free_ze то Ваш комментарий не совсем верен :) В частности, в ответе я показал, что `inline` не обязан быть в хедере.

Comment: @alexolut Вы уже цепляетесь) про хэдер - уточнение для конкретного кейса ТС.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать `inline`.

Говорят, смысла нет вручную писать это ключевое слово, ибо современные компиляторы на него не реагируют и инлайнят по своему разумению.

Comment: ну Вы бы уж полностью копировали свои комментарии, а то в текущем виде это не тянет на ответ, а только на комментарий. Пожалуйста, добавьте деталей, почему `inline` нужно убрать в этом случае.

Comment: @ixSci При желании вы можете править чужие ответы или добавлять свои. 
У меня нет ответа почему, потому я и не это пишу это в ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Наличие спецификатора `inline` при определении функции с внешней компоновкой (external linkage) в `.cpp` [требует](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#6) дублирования определения функции во всех единицах трансляции, где она используется:

> An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case.

Ваш случай может быть упрощен до [следующего](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RuX73zSLLT01YCVR):

```
// a.h 
#pragma once
struct A {
    void f();
};
```

---

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
inline void A::f() {}
```

---

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.h"
int main() {
   A a;
   a.f(); 
}
```

Модуль `main.cpp` видит объявление `A::f` (из `a.h`), но из-за наличия `inline` не видит определение `A::f` (т.е. в `main.cpp` оно отсутствует). Решить проблему можно:

- [либо](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QHAq7bxHPcTPbgRE) убрав `inline`, и сделав реализацию доступной другим единицам трансляции;
- [либо](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XWpdz4tDmMeb8Af4) поместив в `main.cpp` точно такое же определение функции, что и в `a.cpp`.